# Probably grep, but still do not get how to read row in file1 and paste it as a column in file2

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep, command

I have a CSV file like this:

> (A),4.999165E-08,5.99986E-08,7.000066E-08,8.000618E-08, etc.,.

All I want to do is make an output (without commas) in a form of column in another CSV file, so it should look like:

> (A)
>
> 4.999165E-08
>
> 5.99986E-08
>
> 7.000066E-08

I still don't get the basics of grep or it is not possible and should I use awk command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file looks like what you mentioned, then you can just do..

```
tr ',' '\n'
```

An example of what it will do..

```
echo "(A),4.999165E-08,5.99986E-08,7.000066E-08,8.000618E-08, " | tr ',' '\n'
(A)
4.999165E-08
5.99986E-08
7.000066E-08
8.000618E-08
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to use `awk`

```
awk -F, '$1=$1' OFS="\n"
(A)
4.999165E-08
5.99986E-08
7.000066E-08
8.000618E-08
 etc.
```

This is some more robust

```
awk -F, '{$1=$1}1' OFS="\n"
```

Another `awk`

```
awk 'gsub(/,/,"\n")'
```